# How to handle Java return JSONObject variable type if it can be an Array or a String

Tags: java, json, fastjson

I try to parse a JSON file using Alibaba Fastjson Java library.

One of the JSONObject of the file is either an Array or a String.

Below is the Java snippet

```
@JSONField(name="States")
private Object[] states;
```

This can be used when the JSONObject is an array but it will throw an exception when the return type is a String.

Any idea what should I do. The variable type = Object[] seems not good enough.

Comment: @Deadpool The OP is using a different library, so that is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

[@JSONField](https://github.com/alibaba/fastjson/wiki/JSONField) This annotation also can be used on setter method

```
 @JSONField(name="states")
 public void setStates(Object states) {

   if(states instanceof String[]) {
        String[] statesArray = (String[]) states;
        this.states = statesArray;
    } else {
        this.states = new String[] {states.toString()};
    }
 }
```